# Breakdown hierarchy data MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a 3-level Hierarchical Data

[image: Dataset]

I would like to have a break it out and have a table like this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me out?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server.  Conflicting platform tags have been removed.  Please feel free to readd the tag for the platform you are using.

Comment: mysql 8 has recursive CTE, with prior versions this will be tricky

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a recursive-query in some sql framework unless you know the depth of the hierarchy. Here's a link to a MySQL example: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: you're not wrong